# ¿Como descargar una imagen con Vue y axios enviada desde una API Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Actualmente lo hago de la siguiente forma, esto desde el controlador:

```
return response()->download($url,'imagen.jpg')->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Pero quiero hacerlo desde Vue sin necesidad de redireccionar, y recibir la imagen en una petición hecha por axios, por ejemplo:

```
axios.get('/ruta').then(function(response){
    //código para descargar
})
```

Esto es lo que estoy tratando de hacer con el paquete NPM [js-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download):

```
axios.post('/subir-imagen',this.payload).then(function(response){
    fileDownload(response.data, 'filename.jpg');
})
```

Comment: mira si te sirve [Link de ayuda](https://codeday.me/es/qa/20190314/309352.html)

Comment: En parte ayuda, ya que se pueden hacer ciertas pruebas y ver el resultado, pero no me a funcionado como tal, porque, ¿como debería mandar la imagen desde el controlador?, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se resolvió de la siguiente manera:

- Se envió y se trabajo la imagen en el servidor.
- Se guardó y se retornó la url.
- Se obtuvo la url en el response de axios.

  `self = this
  axios.post('/subir-imagen',this.payload).then(function(response){
      if (response.data.estatus = 'si') {
          self.url = response.data.url
      }else{
          Swal.fire('Error',response.data.mensaje,'error')
      }
  })`
- Se guardó la url en una variable de vue y se mostró un preview en un modal el cual tiene un botón de descarga.

  `<a :href="url" download class="btn btn-success">Descargar imagen</a>`

> Si encuentran una forma de hacer la descarga desde el momento que llega como respuesta en axios, se los agradecería mucho, saludos.